# Why do power levels increase when band passing a signal?

Tags: power

[image]
[image]

In this book [design of analog CMOS integrated circuits], it's mentioned that when a white noise spectrum is bandpassed to a certain freqeuncy band, the frequency components from the other bands are folded into the band of interest, increasing the power levels.

I find this a little hard to understand. Why does that happen? Does this also apply to other signals that aren't white too?

Comment: How do you interpret that from the picture you showed?

Comment: @Andyaka Figure 7.10 shows white noise across all frequencies as having an amplitude of n/2, when it is folded and presented only in the positive frequency, the amplitude increases to n. I'm guessing that if I further limit it to 0 and f/2, the ampltiude will increase to 2n.

Comment: The figure is showing conservation of energy, which is not specific to any particular class of signals. What do you find confusing? That positive and negative frequencies exist? That a bandpass filter treats positive and negative frequencies equally? Something else?

Comment: @user1850479 What I find confusing is that when you consider the power spectral density across all frequencies, there is an amplitude of n/2, even at the positive frequencies. However, by just applying a bandpass filter and selecting only positive frequencies and then viewing the spectral density, the amplitude now increases to n. Why does this happen? The concept of folding is what I am confused about and how increases the ampltiude?

Comment: Eqn 7.5 is not selecting only the positive frequencies, it is integrating the positive and negative frequencies and then summing them together. This increases amplitude.